# Why do I have to press the shutter button twice on my Canon 6d Mark II?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, mirror-lockup

I am new to photography and trying to learn everyday. I've noticed when shooting in manual mode and using the Viewfinder like most professionals use, when I press the shutter button down you have to like click it twice in order for it to take the photo. I've watched Youtube videos of pros shooting and they shoot in manual and it snaps the picture quick!

When I press it down it's like something inside the camera closes, and then when I press again it captures the image and the view finder opens back up. I want it to just snap the photo when I press it. I tried turning off the shutter button focus and using the back AF button and it still happens.

Is there a setting I need to change? This is why I liked using the Live View Screen to shoot, because it snaps it right when i want it to. There isn't this, like, double tap on the shutter button.

Comment: Do you notice that difference when the lens is in manual focus as well?

Comment: You normally don't push twice, but push to first click to make the camera focus, and then push more/deeper to trigger. With a good camera you can push all the way down at once.

Comment: Its like the camera shuts then opens and captures the camera? I cant figure out how to get a fast snap? its so weird

Comment: You say you have to push the shutter button twice — what exactly happens when you do it just once?

Comment: Also, what happens if you 1) press all the way down and hold? Or 2) press just lightly, but not all the way down?

Comment: When i press it down its like something inside the camera closes and then when you press again it captures the image and the view finder opens back up. I want it to just snap the photo when I press it. I tried turning off the shutter button focus and using the back AF button and its still happens..

Answer (score 8):

> When i press it down its like something inside the camera closes and then when you press again it captures the image and the view finder opens back up

This sounds like Mirror Lock Up functionality. This mode allows one to separate the mechanism for the mirror and shutter so as to allow for any vibrations caused by the mirror to dissipate before taking the photo. It’s for use in situations where those vibrations may ruin your shot (slow shutter speeds)

Check to make sure that you don’t have MLU enabled. As was commented, using default settings, a half press should engage autofocus and a full press should take the shot. (I say ‘using default settings’ because you can change this behavior. Look into the custom function for back-button focus. Easily one of the most useful custom functions, especially for sports/fast action shooting)

Comment: OMG You FIXED it!!!!! Thank you so much for your time and efforts. I can finally sleep now haha! I've been trying to figure this out for days and losing hope!

Comment: Hi shelbi. I'm glad Hueco's answer worked for you. Please don't forget to show the ultimate appreciation and mark this answer as the accepted answer (the checkbox under the vote buttons near the upper left of the answer). Thanks, and welcome to Photo-SE! =)